# On wreath product of finite $p$-groups

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, p-groups, wreath-product

Actually, I was studying about the group $ C_p \wr C_p$, where $C_p$ is cyclic group of order $p$ and $\wr$ denotes the wreath product. I understood that it is isomorphic to the Sylow $p$-Subgroup of $S_{p^2}$. I was wondering if I can get a subgroup inside $GL(n,p^k)$, for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$ which is isomorphic to $C_p \wr C_p$?

Comment: Please edit to clarify what SSG is.

Comment: $S_{p^2}$ is inside $GL(p^2, 2)$ by the Cayley theorem.

Comment: @JCAA Kindly provide the proof.

Comment: Search for linear permutation representation.

Comment: @JCAA Why have you chosen the base field $\mathbb{F_2}$ ?

Comment: Field does not matter. Entries of the matrices are 0, 1. So you can choose any field you want.

Comment: @JCAA Thanks a lot ! It really helped me.

Comment: @JCAA $GL(p^2,2)$ is quite different from $GL(n, p^k)$ don't you think?

Comment: @QuangHoang: As I said you can replace $2$ by any field you want, for example by $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$, and $n$ in the OP it not specified, it can be $p^2$.

Answer (score 0):

One may find $P\cong C_p\wr C_p$ in the group $\mathrm{GL}_{2p}(p)$. The construction is fairly reasonable.

First, the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}_2(p^p)$ is elementary abelian of order $p^p$. The field automorphism of order $p$ on $\mathrm{SL}_2(p^p)$ acts on this Sylow $p$-subgroup, and constructs exactly your group, $C_p\wr C_p$. So now we want a faithful representation of $G=\mathrm{SL}_2(p^p)\rtimes C_p$. I claim there is a $2p$-dimensional representation of this group over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

To see this, notice that $\mathrm{SL}_2(p^p)$ has $p$ different (faithful) representations of dimension $2$. Its natural representation is one, and then its twist under the Frobenius map, obtained by mapping $x\in \mathbb F_{p^p}$ to $x^p$. This is a field automorphism, and gives us $p$ different representations. The sum of all of these is of dimension $2p$, and is stable under the Frobenius map, by construction. This means that it is conjugate in $\mathrm{GL}_{2p}(p^p)$ to a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_{2p}(p)$.

The final bit is to note that the field automorphism of $\mathrm{SL}_2(p^p)$ still normalizes this subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_{2p}(p)$, and so we find all of $C_p\wr C_p$ as a subgroup of this group.

---

If one prefers cross-characteristic (i.e., over fields of characteristic different from $p$) representations, then one may do better than $\mathrm{GL}_{p^2}(\mathbb{C})$, and it lies in $\mathrm{GL}_p(\mathbb{C})$. One sees this by simply inducing a linear character from the subgroup of index $p$.

Comment: Can you please suggest me some reference where I can find what you have written ? Actually, I am not so much advanced in my knowledge. Therefore, I am finding it difficult to understand, what you are explaining.

Comment: What do you need the wreath product as a subgroup of a matrix group for? My construction is useful in some situations, but is unlikely to help you by the sounds of it.

Comment: I need it to be isomorphic to some subgroup containing either only upper/lower triangular matrices or containing some other kind of matrices, so that I can define a new binary operation on that subgroup to make it elementary abelian $p$-group. In case of upper/lower triangular matrix subgroup, I already have an operation, which serves my purpose. So, it will be good if I can show to isomorphic to some subgroup of Sylow p-subgroup of $GL(n,p^k)$. Right ?

Comment: You know that, over a field of characteristic $p$, any finite $p$-group that is a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n(k)$ is conjugate to a group of upper unitriangular matrices, right?

Comment: Ohh !! yesss, Thank you for your precious time and suggestions.